# dnd-kit show preview line while dragging items in a list

Tags: drag-and-drop, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd, dnd-kit

It's not clear how to display a light blue preview line in a list when dragging items in a sortable list. It's not clear in the docs or examples.

https://master--5fc05e08a4a65d0021ae0bf2.chromatic.com/?path=/docs/examples-pages-layout--grid

In the examples section, both the pages and tree examples at the bottom have preview lines but its not clear at all how to create that.

I want to display a horizontal preview line similar to notion when you drag items around. Has anyone managed to do this?